# What's the purpose of ReflectionFunctionAbstract::getClosureThis()?

Tags: php, closures, php-5.3

Along with the introduction of [Closures](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) in PHP 5.3, has been introduced a [getClosureThis()](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunctionabstract.getclosurethis.php) method on [ReflectionFunctionAbstract](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunctionabstract.php).

Anyone has an idea what it is for? The doc does not say anything about it, Google has been useless so far, and my attempts on different ReflectionFunction/ReflectionMethod objects have all returned `NULL`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it says:

> Returns this pointer bound to closure

So if you have PHP 5.4:

```
<?php
class MyObj {}
$foo = function() { };
$obj = new MyObj;
$foo = $foo->bindTo($obj); // Inside the newly returned closure, $this == $obj
$reflector = new ReflectionFunction($foo);
assert($obj === $reflector->getClosureThis());
```

i.e., It returns the closure's `$this` pointer.